# Editing about:config values from commandline

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, command-line

Is it possible to edit `about:config` parameters from command-line on Ubuntu desktops ?

Comment: Rather than stealing someone's thunder, I'll point you [here, which has an accepted answer on how to accomplish this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/32631/how-to-configure-firefox-from-terminal)